# How to detect the event when a user is logging on?

Tags: c++, windows, winlogon

Is there a way to detect when a user is logging on a system? I found a method as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375405(v=vs.85).aspx but it doesn't work on Windows Vista and hihgher. So does anyone has an idea how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [`WTSWaitSystemEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383856.aspx) with `WTS_EVENT_LOGON` might be what you are looking for.